# "Cannot build classfiles for source directories" Openbravo. JSP

Tags: xml, netbeans, jsp, tomcat

Resulta que quiero modificar un modulo PDA que trae el punto de venta Open Bravo.
Importe el proyecto a Netbeans.
Todo está en orden. Librerías requeridas, servidor Tomcat con xampp, java 1.6. Todo, pero al tratar de ejecutar, me dice:

> ```
> C:\Users\Ayram\Documents\PDAdef\nbproject\build-impl.xml:861: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> ```

Que contiene:

```
webproject2:javac destdir="${build.classes.dir}" gensrcdir="${build.generated.sources.dir}"
```

Otra linea que dice:

> ```
> C:\Users\Ayram\Documents\PDAdef\nbproject\build-impl.xml:293: 
> Cannot build classfiles for source directories:
> [C:\Users\Ayram\Documents\PDAdef\src-pda, 
> C:\Users\Ayram\Documents\PDAdef\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output]
> ```

Y contiene:

```
javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}"
```

He probado soluciones como crear un proyecto nuevo en lugar de importar el existente, borrar "build-impl.xml" y reemplazarlo con otro existente.
Desmarcar la casilla "Use IDE proxy Settings" de la pestaña Plataform, cambiar de plataforma 1.6 a 1.8.

He buscado e intentado muchas cosas y no tengo ningún resultado.

Las referencias para lo que trato de hacer, están en
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/POS/Openbravo_POS_Developer_Guide
El código fuente del proyecto está en:

sourceforge.net/projects/openbravopos/files/Openbravo%20POS/Openbravo%20POS%202.30.2/openbravopos_2.30.2_src.zip/download

Si no quieren descargarlo, no requieren hacerlo. Pueden visualizarlo desde:

javased. com/index.php?source_dir=Openbravo-POS-iPhone-App/OpenbravoPOS_PDA/src-pda/com/openbravo/pos/pda/